# Docker file, symlink disappears mid build

Tags: bash, shell, docker, dockerfile, symlink

I have the following docker file (at the bottom). I am using another image to grab a precompiled library (utilities) and copying it into the route of a new image. I then need to symlink that directory into my node_modules directory. This works fine, I have 3 places where I prove the issue.

1. Check for the existence of the original root directory /utilities. This works, I can see the files

   - Then I create the symlink: `ln -sf ...`
2. I think check to see the contents at the location of the symlink. This works, I can see the files.

   - I go on to create the rest of the image
3. At the end I again list out the files, and now I get

   ```
   ls: /usr/src/app/node_modules/@boiler/utilities: No such file or directory
   ```

It's like the symlink doesn't persist. If I run the container with shell: `docker run -it --entrypoint=sh backend:latest` and create the symlink it works.

Any thoughts as to where my symlink is going?

```
FROM utilities-setup:latest as build

FROM node:8.5.0-alpine
COPY --from=build /utilities /utilities
RUN ls -l /utilities <-- 1. THIS WORKS, FILES EXIST

#setup directories
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/node_modules/@boiler/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

#create symlink to the utilities module into the boiler module
RUN ln -sf /utilities /usr/src/app/node_modules/@boiler/

RUN ls /usr/src/app/node_modules/@boiler/utilities <-- 2. THIS WORKS, FILES EXIST

#copy the content of the backend to the current direcotry
COPY . .
RUN yarn install
RUN ls /usr/src/app/node_modules/@boiler/utilities <-- 3. THIS FAILS, NO MODULE

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./scripts/prod.sh"]
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/scripts/prod.sh"]
```

Comment: I was gonna delete this as I clocked it. But I thought someone else may have a similar issue. What was happening was the `yarn install` was recreating the node_modules directory, so you have to create the symlink after all other modules are installed. Makes sense I suppose, but I thought it would just write to the directory if it already existed

Comment: Please post that as an answer and check it so that the question no longer shows as open. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[see comment] I clocked the problem. 
What was happening was the yarn install was recreating the node_modules directory, so you have to create the symlink after all other modules are installed. Makes sense I suppose, but I thought it would just write to the directory if it already existed